# How do I rescue Barla Von's Shadow Broker forces?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I talked to Liara who, in turn, sent me to Barla Von who, in turn, wants me to rescue his Shadow Broker buddies in the Dranek system. That's all well and good, but when I get to the Dranek systemm there's nothing there.

I feel like some sort of squad combat sequence was supposed to be triggered at some point and my game is just bugged. Or am I just missing something obvious?

**Where and how do I rescue the trapped Shadow Broker forces?**

Comment: This might be one of the times where you just scan and probe to retrieve them. Did you scan the system?

Comment: this is a plain old scan/probe, not an actual combat mission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Shadow Broker Wet Squad war asset, and it's located on Rothla in the Dranec System.  You'll have to scan for it and then probe the planet.  Make sure to go back to Barla Von before starting Priority Tuchanka.